# Fragments android

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Допустим у меня следующая архитектура: есть активность, в разметке активности есть FrameLayout и кнопки управления. По нажатию на эти кнопки у меня в FrameLayout, загружаются разные фрагменты. Вопрос следующий, стоит ли мне хранить в активности для каждого фрагмента по 1 экземпляру и их загружать в FrameLayout, либо создавать каждый раз новый фрагмент. Как правильнее сделать и почему?

Comment: Инстансы фрагментов хранятся в фрагмент менеджере, вам самому их хранить не нужно.

Answer (score 1):

Вот вам отличный [туториал](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments?hl=RU) по фрагментам.

Управление фрагментами осуществляется посредством **FragmentManager**. Все операции с фрагментами (добавление, удаление) осуществляется посредством **FragmentTransaction**. Один раз создав фрагмент его можно больше не создавать, а найти по тегу, если он еще нужен. Тоже самое касается addToBackStack(), чтобы была возможность вернуться назад. То как вы будете использовать фрагменты зависит полностью от потребностей приложения.